# Guitar pup problems

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups

I was practicing with my Epi Les Paul traditional pro and my strap slipped off. The guitar fell on the floor without any cosmetic damages but after strumming all the strings, it sounded differently, like a somewhat distortion. Plus, one of the pups are poking out a little. I tried pushing that in but its not budging. Also I practice with an Fender Mustang V2 amp

Comment: The "Distortion" sound you mention is hard to be sure about, but it could be the string rattling against something, or a loose component vibrating when the strings are played, etc. Also, a poor connection in the pickup switch can sometimes cause in intermittent sound that's a bit like distortion.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch - I hate it when that happens.  Hopefully your guitar did not suffer irreparable damage.

Several things could be going on with one (or both) of your pickups.  The first thing you might try - **IF but only if**, you have the correct sized small screwdriver (so you don't strip the screw heads) is tightening the screws on the corners of the pickup bezel.  Don't over tighten but just be sure none of them are loose.  Hopefully the only issue is that one of the screws is simply loose and will tighten back up and everything will be fine.

If that fails to work or if either the screws all seem tight or one of them won't tighten up, then you may have a problem that needs the attention of a qualified guitar repair technician.  If the substrate which holds the screws (what the screws screw into) has been damaged, it may need to be repaired.

Another thing that may have happened is that a wire for one of the pickups inside the guitar has come loose or come into contact with another wire. If a solder joint breaks but the wire still touches the lug or contact, the pickup may still work but sound strange (or only work sporadically).  If it was me, I would probably let someone else remove the plate on the back of the guitar behind the knobs and/or the pickups to check for a loose wire.  It's possible a wire may need to be soldered back where it belongs.

The good news is, electrical issues are often easier to repair with perfect results than cosmetic issues.  So it's a good thing your guitar did not sustain any cracks or chips or dings.

In the future, you might want to consider using a straplock button like the one pictured below.

[image: Straplock Button]

Good luck!